# ASUS Realtek audio, sound seems to be stuck at 1% for speakers

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

At current I've spent the last 10 hours trying to get my sound back... Last night my computer froze up and I had to reset the BIOS. After I got my computer back online my sound was not working. I can barely hear sound coming out of the speakers as if the sound is set to 1% full volume. I can't seem to get it any louder and this makes no sense at all.

What I've tried:

1. I tried turning off the sound in BIOS and back on again, that did not work.
2. I've tried uninstalling the driver and reinstalling drivers from ASUS and the latest ones from Realtek, did not work. I also tried uninstalling it completely and allowing windows to take control, no luck there either.
3. I've checked all levels to make sure sound wasn't muted or set to a low volume, all available settings show sound is at 100% and nothing is muted.
4. I've tried turning on "loudness equalization" on and off and no difference. I've tried turning all sound enhancements off and no change.
5. I've tried changing the sound format, tried all options available and no difference.
6. I've checked device manager to make sure not conflicts or driver issues, everything shows correctly.
7. I've tried using all the ports on the back, double, triple, quadruple checked that and it's plugged into the right port.
8. I've tested the speakers with a different device and they work with other devices so not a speaker or receiver issue.

I can see the sound working as the sound bar shows green up and down as sounds are made and as I said if I put my ear really close to the speakers i can barely hear the sound, so sound is coming from it a little bit. It was working fine before the computer crashed on me. I'm at a loss at this point.

The only thing that was different prior to this happening is I got a new headset by Turtle Beach, uses a USB dongle, wireless. I noticed when I first hooked it up and turned on the headset that it automatically switched me to the headset and then muted the sound on my system speakers. I'd turn them off and it would reverse things back to the speakers and it was working fine all day yesterday that way.

Anyway, not sure what's up at this point. I do not want to have to buy a new mother board just for a sound issue and I'm pretty sure the sound works and it's probably a driver or conflict of some kind or maybe even due to the new headset. Maybe the headset set it to mute and when the computer crashed it was unable to switch it back?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Boot live Linux distro that gives you desktop (e.g. Knoppix or Ubuntu installer). If there is no problem with sound in Linux then you will know your hardware is fine.

Comment: I will try this and let you know the results. For now I've simply bypassed the issue by using a USB sound card as mentioned below, but that is not the ideal solution, for my on board sound is a lot nicer. Anyway, I'll try this and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have had some issues with system sound like this, and my solution is to simply add a USB sound unit.  Once it is plugged in, you can right-click on the speaker and go into the Playback Options and set the USB PnP as your default.

Be sure to go into the Levels tab and set it to 100% so Windows has control of the volume.  That goes for microphones, also, but in the Recording Options section.

Here is the kind of unit I use.  They are $10 for a 2-pack:

[https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-2-Pack-Adapter-Windows/dp/B012E4CUPC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012E4CUPC)

Comment: That could be a solution. I was thinking too I may just buy a sound card and disable the on board sound, but if i can get the on board sound working that would be the ideal solution.

Comment: I like the comment above about booting up with a LiveCD Linux distro.  If that works then you know your problem is not hardware.